# Cannot resolve 'spring-boot-starter-request-jpa' with Gradle dependency using invalid URL

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a dependency on the `spring-boot-starter-request-jpa`. It appears that the dependency is trying to resolve using an invalid URL.

```
Error:Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-request-jpa:.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.jar
    file:/Users/*removed*/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.pom
    file:/Users/*removed*/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.jar
    http://server.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.pom
    http://server.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.jar
Required by:
    project :MobileAPI
```

My gradle configuration was working fine about 12 hours ago with no changes.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "${nexusRepoUrl}"
    }
}
```

In the error, the URL & path it is using `https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-request-jpa//spring-boot-starter-request-jpa-.pom` has a double forward slash now.

I was using Gradle 3.1 with this error, I have tried upgrading to Gradle 3.4.1 but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I just realized now that Intellij refactored the dependency name when i changed a class name :-p. Be careful when refactoring!